# Iterate through elements

Tags: cypress

I have a page with a few `Results` panels, each panel has its own delete button.

I wrote a Cypress test to test the delete process, the test works as expected, the panel gets deleted:

```
cy.get('div[data-test="Results"]')
  .first()
  .within(() => {
    cy.get('p[data-test="Contact ID"]').then($match => {
      contactID = $match.html();
      cy.get('button[data-test="Delete Contact"]')
        .click()
        .get('div[data-test="Delete Record Modal"]')
        .should('be.visible')
        .get('button[data-test="Confirm Deletion"]')
        .click();
    });
  });
```

Next I'm trying to detect if the correct panel got deleted.
How can I iterate through all the `<p />`s of all panels and make sure none of them has a `contactID` equal to the one that was deleted?

I tried this:

```
cy.get('p[data-test="ContactID"]').then($match2 => {
  expect($match2.text()).not.to.eq(contactID);
});
```

But in `$match2` I get all contacts ids all together for example: `12345678` instead of `1234` and `5678`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `each`:

```js
cy.get('p[data-test="ContactID"]').each(($match) => {
  cy.wrap($match).invoke('text').should('not.eq', contactID)
})
```

- `invoke` calls a function on the subject, in this case, `.text()`
- the chained `.should` makes an assertion on that text
- this will retry the assertion until it passes or times out (see [retry-ability](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/retry-ability.html)) due to the `cy.wrap`

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly! Would you be able to add a short explanation? Also, is there a better way to get the actual text of the `p` instead of doing that:  `cy.get('p[data-test="Contact ID"]').then($match => {
      contactID = $match.html();`?

Comment: But do I need the `.then`? There is no way to do it without callbacks?

Comment: you'll still need the `.then`

Comment: @user3378165 also make sure to use the updated code, using `invoke` instead of `its('text')`